# i was building an old version of ionic app ending up having this error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I was going to add a new plugin to this app, it works fine on ionic serve but when i decide to build it using ionic cordova build android ending up having this error

```
   > npm run ionic:build:before

> project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project
> node ./bin/www/script.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/bin/www/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before: `node ./bin/www/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/roben/.npm/_logs/2018-09-25T13_12_14_615Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm run ionic:build:before exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

the output of ionic cordova build android --verbose

```
> npm run ionic:build:before
> project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project> node ./bin/www/script.jsmodule.js:550    throw err;
    ^Error: Cannot find module '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/projectbin/www/script.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before: `node ./bin/www/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/roben/.npm/_logs/2018-09-25T15_55_42_452Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm run ionic:build:before exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ rm -rf node_modules
^C
CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$
CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ rm -rf node_modules
CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ npm install

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node
Download complete  ⸩ ⠋ :
Binary saved to /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57/binding.node
Caching binary to /Users/roben/.npm/node-sass/4.9.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
added 901 packages from 742 contributors and audited 4018 packages in 34.635s
found 0 vulnerabilities

CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ ionic corodva build android
[ERROR] Unable to find command: corodva build android

   _             _
  (_) ___  _ __ (_) ___
  | |/ _ \| '_ \| |/ __|
  | | (_) | | | | | (__
  |_|\___/|_| |_|_|\___|  CLI PRO 4.1.2


  Usage:

    $ ionic <command> [<args>] [--help] [--verbose] [--quiet] [--no-interactive] [--no-color] [--confirm] [options]

  Global Commands:

    config <subcommand> ...... Manage CLI and project config values (subcommands: get,
                               set, unset)
    docs ..................... Open the Ionic documentation website
    info ..................... Print project, system, and environment information
    login .................... Login to Ionic Pro
    logout ................... Logout of Ionic Pro
    signup ................... Create an account for Ionic Pro
    ssh <subcommand> ......... Commands for configuring SSH keys (subcommands: add,
                               delete, generate, list, setup, use)
    start .................... Create a new project

  Project Commands:

    build .................... Build web assets and prepare your app for any platform
                               targets
    capacitor <subcommand> ... (beta) Capacitor functionality (subcommands: add, copy,
                               open, run, sync, update) (alias: cap)
    cordova <subcommand> ..... Cordova functionality (subcommands: build, compile,
                               emulate, platform, plugin, prepare, requirements,
                               resources, run)
    doctor <subcommand> ...... Commands for checking the health of your Ionic project
                               (subcommands: check, list, treat)
    generate ................. Automatically create framework features (alias: g)
    git <subcommand> ......... Commands relating to git (subcommands: remote)
    integrations <subcommand>  Manage various integrations in your app (subcommands:
                               disable, enable, list)
    link ..................... Connect local apps to Ionic Pro
    monitoring <subcommand> .. Commands relating to Ionic Pro error monitoring
                               (subcommands: syncmaps)
    serve .................... Start a local dev server for app dev/testing (alias: s)
    ssl <subcommand> ......... (experimental) Commands for managing SSL keys &
                               certificates (subcommands: generate)

CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ ionic cordova build android
> npm run ionic:build:before

> project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project
> node ./bin/www/script.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/bin/www/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before: `node ./bin/www/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/roben/.npm/_logs/2018-09-25T16_22_18_392Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm run ionic:build:before exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ ionic cordova build android --verbose
  ionic:cli-utils Terminal info: { tty: true, ci: false } +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'android' ], help: null,h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json:null, project: null, '--': [] } +4ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:project Project type from config: Ionic Angular 3 (ionic-angular) +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils Project name: undefined +279ms
  ionic:cli Context: { binPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic', libPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic', execPath: '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project', version: '4.1.2' } +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:integrations:cordova:config Using config.xml: /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/config.xml +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:hooks Invoking ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
> npm run ionic:build:before

> project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project
> node ./bin/www/script.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/bin/www/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before: `node ./bin/www/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before script.
CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ ionic cordova build android --verbose  ionic:cli-utils Terminal info: { tty: true, ci: false } +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'android' ], help: null,
h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json:
null, project: null, '--': [] } +2ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:project Project type from config: Ionic Angular 3 (ionic-angular) +0
ms
  ionic:cli-utils Project name: undefined +132ms
  ionic:cli Context: { binPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic', libPath: '/
usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic', execPath: '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project', version: '4.1.2' } +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:integrations:cordova:config Using config.xml: /Users/roben/Desktop/i
onic/project/config.xml +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:hooks Invoking ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
> npm run ionic:build:before

> project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project
> node ./bin/www/script.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/bin/www/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before: `node ./bin/www/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before script.
CurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ ionic cordova build android --verbosCurlyBrketssMBP:project roben$ ionic cordova build android --verbose
  ionic:cli-utils Terminal info: { tty: true, ci: false } +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'android' ], help: null,
h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json:
null, project: null, '--': [] } +3ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:project Project type from config: Ionic Angular 3 (ionic-angular) +0
ms
  ionic:cli-utils Project name: undefined +132ms
  ionic:cli Context: { binPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic', libPath: '/
usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic', execPath: '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project', version: '4.1.2' } +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:integrations:cordova:config Using config.xml: /Users/roben/Desktop/i
onic/project/config.xml +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:cli-utils:lib:hooks Invoking ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
> npm run ionic:build:before

> project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before /Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project
> node ./bin/www/script.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/roben/Desktop/ionic/project/bin/www/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before: `node ./bin/www/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.1 ionic:build:before script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/roben/.npm/_logs/2018-09-26T06_32_36_084Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm run ionic:build:before exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: process.exit received +0ms
  ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 queued functions +0ms
  ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: exiting (exit code 1) +23ms
```

Current node version

```
node -v
v8.12.0
```

Cordova version

```
cordova -version
8.0.0
```

npm version

```
npm -v
6.4.1
```

Other:

```
 "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.9",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
```

additional information:
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

NodeJS : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode  : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000

Comment: What's the output of `ionic cordova build android --verbose`? Do you have any errors running `npm i`?

Comment: i edit my post to includes the ionic cordova build android --verbose and make sure that npm i is error free

Comment: Have you tried removing android platform and re-adding it back? I've had issues like this and adding the platform fixed the npm errors. Use ionic cordova platform rm android and then ionic cordova platform add android. When adding it, check the plugins that are attached in the console to see if the plugin you added was attached as well.

Comment: yes i've try this several times just having the same error every time i try to use ionic cordova run/build android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix the error there was a script file missing so i have to create a new directory bin containing "www/script.js" in it
the problem is solved !!